# Why does a batch file working before not work anymore as expected on some machines?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script already working for some months. The purpose of the script is to  create a folder based on the file name and rename the folder accordingly for a certain purpose. However, it stops moving the files to the created folder in the loop. I tested it on other machine and it was working fine, but on a particular machine; it is just not working.

What can I do to make the loop effective and why did the batch stop working (moving files to folder) after working for many months now?

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('dir "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted" /a-d /b') do (
    if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"

:func
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~0,49%
mkdir "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%dir%_fdc" 2>nul

rem ECHO "%file%"
rem ECHO "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%dir%_fdc" 

move /Y "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%file%" "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%dir%_fdc"  
)

start "" "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\hide_conversion_window.exe"
```

Comment: What is the error you see? I can already see a bracket ) missing in the for loop at the start.

Comment: I have not seen any error after I remove the @echo off.  Please tell me where the missing bracket ) is because I could not find where is missing.   Thanks

Comment: Thanks,  I have spotted it and will let you know now if it works... . for /F %%a in ('dir "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted" /a-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a" )

Comment: Thanks Mofi. Cheers !  You are very correct. It is quite strange that something do work and then suddenly stop because it is not right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote and commented the batch file as it contains several issues whereby most were not problematic as long as this batch file is stored in `%ProgramFiles%\WinSCP\Unconverted` and this directory is also the current directory on execution of the batch file as on double clicking the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=%ProgramFiles%\WinSCP\Unconverted"

rem Process all files in source folder found by command DIR with ignoring
rem subfolders and listed in bare format which means only file names with
rem file extension but without file path. The batch file itself is skipped
rem if being also stored in the source folder specified above.

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    if /I not "%SourceFolder%\%%I"=="%~f0" call :MoveFile "%SourceFolder%\%%I"
)

rem Execute converter through AutoIt in a separate command process and
rem while conversion is running continue with batch processing which means
rem restoring previous environment and finally exiting batch file processing.

start "" "%ProgramFiles%\WinSCP\hide_conversion_window.exe"
endlocal
goto :EOF

rem MoveFile is a subroutine which expects to be called with one argument
rem being the name of the file to move with full file name which means
rem with file path, file name and file extension.

rem The first 49 characters of the file name define the name for target
rem folder on which "_fdc" must be appended for completion. This folder
rem is created without verification on success and then the file is
rem moved into this folder again without verification on success.

:MoveFile
set "FileName=%~nx1"
set "FolderName=%FileName:~0,49%_fdc"
mkdir "%~dp1\%FolderName%" 2>nul
move /Y "%~1" "%~dp1\%FolderName%\" >nul
goto :EOF
```

This batch file works for batch file being stored in a different folder than source folder or current directory is a different directory than the folder containing the batch file or a found file contains a space character or any other special character like `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion oldabi. Sometimes things do work and we are thinking is all perfect until it breaks down. Thanks for the suggestion. I just realised my mistake about missing bracket.

```
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F %%a in ('dir "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted" /a-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a" )

goto conversion

  :conversion
rem ::execute converter through autoit
start "" "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\hide_conversion_window.exe"


:func
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~0,49%
mkdir "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%dir%_fdc" 2>nul

rem  ECHO "%file%"
rem ECHO "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%dir%_fdc" 

MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%file%" "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted\%dir%_fdc"
```